# Web Services' Create Java Bean Skeleton - Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I am trying to generate a java bean skeleton using Eclipse's Web Services from the WSDL. I am selecting 'Top Down Java bean Web Service' for type and am using 'Apache CXF 2.x' for the Web Service run time.

> IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.
>    org.eclipse.emf.common.util.DiagnosticException: A problem was detected while >parsing a Java file
>        org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: >org.eclipse.emf.common.util.DiagnosticException: A problem was detected while >parsing a Java file
>        at >org.eclipse.emf.codegen.merge.java.facade.ast.ASTFacadeHelper.createCompilation>Unit(ASTFacadeHelper.java:280)
>        at >org.eclipse.emf.codegen.merge.java.facade.ast.ASTFacadeHelper.createCompilation>Unit(ASTFacadeHelper.java:1)
>        at >org.eclipse.emf.codegen.merge.java.JMerger.createCompilationUnitForInputStream(>JMerger.java:322)
>        at >org.eclipse.emf.codegen.merge.java.JMerger.createCompilationUnitForInputStream(>JMerger.java:311)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.MergeUtils.merge(MergeUtils.java:57)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:12>0)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>71)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>81)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>69)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>81)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>69)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>81)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>69)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>81)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyFolder(FileUtils.java:>69)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.core.utils.FileUtils.copyW2JFilesFromTmp(FileUt>ils.java:180)
>        at >org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.creation.core.commands.WSDL2JavaCommand.execute>(WSDL2JavaCommand.java:82)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCom>mand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:419)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitT>op(CommandFragmentEngine.java:359)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveFo>rwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:212)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.ru>n(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:294)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:4>64)
>        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
>        at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1028)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runF>orwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:264)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToN>extStop(WizardPageManager.java:91)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(W>izardPageManager.java:154)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(Si>mpleWizardPage.java:136)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:908)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:428)
>        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:628)
>        at >org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
>        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
>        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
>        at >org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(Dy>namicPopupWizard.java:130)
>        at >org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionCon>tributionItem.java:584)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem>.java:501)
>        at >org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributio>nItem.java:411)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
>        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
>        at >org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderin>gEngine.java:1113)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>        at >org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingE>ngine.java:997)
>        at >org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.jav>a:140)
>        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:611)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>        at >org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
>        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
>        at >org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.jav>a:124)
>        at >org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196>)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ecl>ipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLa>uncher.java:79)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
>        at >org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
>        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>        at >sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>        at >sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja>va:43)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
>        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
>        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
>        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
>        Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.DiagnosticException: A problem was >detected while parsing a Java file
>        ... 69 more

Additionally, the Eclipse console reads:

> Mar 02, 2016 12:51:52 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder ?>checkForWrapped
>   INFO: Operation {http://example.net/}EPIClientInquiry cannot be ?>unwrapped, input message must reference global element declaration with same >localname as operation

I know there is no problem with the WSDL - a colleague of mine is able to successfully generate the java bean skeleton in his environment. We are using the same JDK, the same Tomcat Server, and the same Apache CXF.
My best guess is that it has something to do with the Eclipse workspace.

I have spent days on this problem, so any help or recommendations are much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project and rebuild again.